# Understanding how to delete new dynamically allocated variables

Tags: c++

This code is to simulate a train where you start with an engine and you can add train cars, detach train cars and move between train cars. I have no problem with that but I have a problem with deleting all my new boxes that I have created while adding the trains at the end of the program. I want all my new train cars to remain until the user quits. At that point, I want to delete all the new boxes. How do I do that? I tried adding a destructor to my class with "delete next;" and "delete previous;" but the program had a run time error. I am new to pointers and dynamic memory and I want to know how to do that. Thanks very much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class train{
    public:
        train(string n);
        bool hasNext();
        bool hasPrevious();
        string getName();
        train* nextTrain();
        train* previousTrain();
        void add(string);
        void detach();
    private:
        string name;
        train* nextTrn;
        train* previousTrn;
};

void train::detach()
{
    if(previousTrn -> hasPrevious())
    {
        previousTrn = previousTrn -> previousTrn;
        delete previousTrn -> nextTrn;
        previousTrn -> nextTrn = this;
    }
    else
        delete previousTrn;
}

train::train(string n)
{
    name = n;
    nextTrn = NULL;
    previousTrn = NULL;
}

void train::add(string n)
{
    train* x = new train(n);
    if(hasPrevious())
    {
        x -> previousTrn = previousTrn;
        x -> previousTrn -> nextTrn = x;
    }
    previousTrn = x;
    x -> nextTrn = this;
}

train* train::nextTrain()
{
    return nextTrn;
}

train* train::previousTrain()
{
    return previousTrn;
}

bool train::hasNext()
{
    if(nextTrn != NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool train::hasPrevious()
{
    if(previousTrn != NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

string train::getName()
{
    return name;
}


int main()
{
    train engine = train("Engine");
    train* current = &engine;
    string choice;
    do
    {
        if(current -> hasNext())
        {
            cout << "Next train: " << current -> nextTrain() -> getName() << endl;
        }

        cout << "Current train: " << current -> getName() << endl;

        if(current -> hasPrevious())
        {
            cout << "Previous train: " << current -> previousTrain() -> getName() << endl;
        }

        cout << "Do you wish to go to the (n)ext train, (p)revious train, (a)dd a train, (d)etach a train, or (q)uit?\n";
        getline(cin,choice);

        if(tolower(choice[0]) == 'n' && current -> hasNext())
        {
            current = current -> nextTrain();
        }
        else if(tolower(choice[0]) == 'p' && current -> hasPrevious())
        {
            current = current -> previousTrain();
        }
        else if(tolower(choice[0]) == 'a')
        {
            cout << "Which train is this?\n";
            string name;
            getline(cin, name);
            current->add(name);
        }   
        else if(tolower(choice[0]) == 'd' && current -> hasPrevious())
        {
            current->detach();
        }           

    }while(tolower(choice[0]) != 'q');

    current = &engine;
    while(current -> hasPrevious())
    {
        current = current -> previousTrain();
        delete current -> nextTrain();
    }
    delete current;
}
```

Comment: This is a design issue. For one, recursive `delete next;` styled code is error prone in my opinion. Your `train` should be a manager class, that manages `car`s. Its destructor should delete all `car`s in a loop.

Comment: @StoryTeller so I should rewrite the whole thing? Or is what I have doable with a small change and I should just take what you're saying into consideration next time I have a program similar?

Comment: You don't *have* to re-write the whole thing. But there are several bugs in your code (i.e. `previousTrn -> hasPrevious()` is undefined behavior if `previousTrn` is a null pointer, and is likely to segfault). The tool to resolve you problem is a debugger, or [something equivalent](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Once you're done debugging, keep what I said in mind for next time, because it will spare you some trouble.

Comment: @StoryTeller it also just deletes allocated objects.. if it is deleted, pointer stays same, pointing to unallocated(invalid memory) not only have to check for null, he have to initialize pointers in constructor and set them to NULL after delete.

Comment: Your train is essentially a linked list. You may check it against hat design pattern?

Comment: @Swift I didn't do a full sweep for bugs, but yeah, you're right. SO isn't the place for such questions anyway. That's why I suggested a debugger and pointed to the blog post by Eric Lippert.